# Direct installation of eclipse neon in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

I just installed Eclipse Neon for ubuntu without using terminal , I unarchived it and ran the program and it installed like in windows. Now when I type eclipse in terminal it can't open it.

I am thinking that any software that is not installed using terminal can't be accessed from it, am I right?

It asks me to install eclipse by using `sudo apt install eclipse-platform` , which means Terminal otherwise my OS has no idea if any program named eclipse is already installed.

Comment: Can you tell us how you installed Eclipse? What archive you downloaded and which program you ran and how? by double clicking or from terminal?

Comment: I downloaded  "eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz" from eclipse website and extracted it and ran the "eclipse-inst" and then a setup as in windows appeared and using GUI I installed eclipse.

Comment: If the link above doesn't help, edit the question including what failed and didn't work

Comment: Thanks , Anwar for the link. But still I have a doubt that when we don't install a software with terminal the terminal or OS have no idea that it is installed unlike windows. Is it true ?

Comment: No, it's not true

Comment: Hi, Sheldon ( looks like someone is Big Bang Theory fan ? )  If you install something, it is on disk , and therefore can be accessed via terminal. Also, your question title is unclear right now. It suggests you want to install eclipse, but really you already did and you want to find it from terminal

Comment: Also, can you provide the link to where i can get the .gz file ?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it

Answer (score 4):

**N.B.**: This answer provides example of my own values. Adjust to your own as necessary

In the beginning of installation, the installer prompts user for installation folder

[image]

In the screenshot , it will be placed into my `~/.eclipse/java-neon`.

So in order to access eclipse from terminal, I have to add it to my `PATH` variable like so:

1. Open `~/.bashrc` with text editor
2. add `$PATH=$PATH:/home/xieerqi/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse/eclipse
3. save and exit.
4. Run `source ~/.bashrc` in terminal

Now , if I run `eclipse` in terminal, it will be launched.

If you also would like to make it openable via Dash or Launcher, you will need to have a `~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` file created

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse
Type=Application
Exec=/home/xieerqi/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/path/to/icon
Terminal=false
```

Note that icon part is optional